# Can a Siamese Network model draw ROC Curve?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, siamese-network

Based on example on Keras
https://keras.io/examples/vision/siamese_contrastive/

Here is how I code to get ROC Curve

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,accuracy_score, roc_curve, auc
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

pred = siamese.predict([x_test_1, x_test_2])
pred = pred[:,0]
pred_NN_01 = np.where(pred > 0.5, 1, 0) #Turn probability to 0-1 binary output
#Print accuracy
acc_NN = accuracy_score(labels_test, pred_NN_01)
print('Overall accuracy of Neural Network model:', acc_NN)

#Print Area Under Curve
false_positive_rate, recall, thresholds = roc_curve(labels_test, pred)
roc_auc = auc(false_positive_rate, recall)
plt.figure()
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC)')
plt.plot(false_positive_rate, recall, 'b', label = 'AUC = %0.3f' %roc_auc)
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.plot([0,1], [0,1], 'r--')
plt.xlim([0.0,1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0,1.0])
plt.ylabel('Recall')
plt.xlabel('Fall-out (1-Specificity)')
plt.show()

#Print Confusion Matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(labels_test, pred_NN_01)
labels = ['Unchange', 'Change']
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
sns.heatmap(cm,xticklabels=labels, yticklabels=labels, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap="Blues", vmin = 0.2);
plt.title('Confusion Matrix')
plt.ylabel('True Class')
plt.xlabel('Predicted Class')
plt.show()
```

[Keras Example ROC Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjpkd.png)

[Keras Example Confusion Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxYV4.png)

If the code and image is right , since the example is 10 classes (0~9 digit image)
how if I use other images which only have two classes with this model
does this ROC Curve code need to change any part?

Because I've got a strange output with this same code with 2 classes

the image result kept weird , the confusion matrix doesn't match the ROC curve

[2 Classes ROC Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOYhU.png)

[2 Classes Confusion Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31uRT.png)

Comment: @itprorh66 In my question , I've already said that what I have tried and what I have done , or is there anything not clear? thanks!!

Comment: What part of solving specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. didn't you understand?  Your question lacks a specific question, also don't post images of code.